# Add and remove classes Angular without controller

Tags: angular

I have just started a new project with angular and I learnt abount *ngIf. I would like to use *ngIf in order to add / remove a class from a div

Before click

```html
<div class="done">Foo</div>
```

After click

```html
<div class="notdone">Foo</div>
```

Comment: use `ngClass` instead of `ngIf` read from here `https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different ways of approaching this.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'done': conditionToDone, 'notdone': !conditionToDone}">Foo</div>
```

Where `done` or `notdone` are added via a condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem. I have to say that you left ' " ' after '{' and before '}' and got an error, but solved quickly!

Comment: Edited my answer. Happy to help.

Comment: Another suggestion: `[ngClass]="condition ? 'done' : 'notdone'"`.